# HTML search field always echoeing zero results

Tags: php, html, search-engine

So basically I'm thinking that adding a search field to my website is out of my league, but internet has so much information that I decided to give it a go.

I started by adding a form to my index pagina, and this is the code I'm using:

```
        <form method="get" action="search.php"> 
            <table cellpadding="0px" cellspacing="0px"> 
              <tr> 
              <td style="border-style:solid none solid solid;border-color:#4B7B9F;border-width:1px;">
                <input type="text" name="q" style="width:100px; border:0px solid; height:17px; padding:0px 3px; position:relative;"> 
              </td>
              <td style="border-style:solid;border-color:#4B7B9F;border-width:1px;"> 
                <input type="submit" value="" style="border-style: none; background: url('images/searchicon.gif') no-repeat; width: 24px; height: 19px;">
              </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
```

Next up, my search.php code:

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 0);
    $search = $_GET ['q'];
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    mysql_select_db("release");
    $query    = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM game WHERE name LIKE '%" . $queryString . "%'");
    $foundnum = mysql_num_rows($query);

     if ($foundnum == 0) {
       echo "No results found. Either this game doesn't exist, or we have yet to add it. Please contact us!";
     }
     else {
       echo "$foundnum results found !<p>";
       $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
     {
       echo '<p>'.$row['game_name'].'</p>';
     }
     }
?>
```

The query continuously echoes the `$foundnum == 0` message even though the data I search for is in the game table.

However, when I try this code:

```
$query    = mysql_query("SELECT game_name FROM game WHERE game_name LIKE '%" . $queryString . "%'");
```

The query prints '35 results found' on my screen. I have 35 entries in the database, but that doesn't make sense (to me) since I'm searching for one game name which is only entered once...

Comment: Try changing your query like this  $query    = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM game WHERE name LIKE '%" . $search . "%'");

Comment: Michael up-vote the answer for others help. thanks.

Comment: I did so in April 2015, Anant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you are using deprecated version mysql_* need to use mysqli_*. Please check below.

```
    <?php
ini_set('display_errors', 2);
$search = $_GET ['q'];
// see changes from below line
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "","release");
$query    = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT game_name FROM game WHERE game_name LIKE '%". $search ."%'");
$foundnum = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
$count = count($foundnum['game_name']);
 if ($foundnum == 0) {
   echo "No results found. Either this game doesn't exist, or we have yet to add it. Please contact us!";
 }
 else {
   echo "$count results found !<p>";
   echo"<pre/>";print_r($foundnum['game_name']);
 }
?>
```

Note:- remove include code from both index and search file that you write on upside.

Comment: Hey. I accidently forgot to change mysql to mysqli, I copied this code from an old Stackoverflow topic. That's my mistake. I'm not getting any results whatsoever when I'm using your code though.

Comment: No, the $foundnum ==0 echo is being shown, even though I'm entering an existing game name in the search field.

Comment: what is your column name in game table . is it name or something else?

Comment: It's game_name. I used that to make sure, but that doesn't fix it.

Comment: try to write  $foundnum = mysqli_fetch_array($query); and then mysqli_error($conn)

Comment: Didn't work out mate. Already so many thanks for trying to help me out here!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75067/discussion-between-michael-cox-and-anant-kumar-singh).

Answer (score 0):

From your second code it seems like there is a typo.

Try changing $query to

```
$query    = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM game WHERE game_name LIKE '%" . $queryString . "%'");
```

and let me know if it works or not :)

Comment: Hey. I tried this but unfortunately every record is echoed, not just the one that is searched for.